# Javascript Add/Remove EventListener not working on run time in jQuery custom functionality

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, anonymous-function, removeeventlistener

My concern is just the function to add eventListner, it works only in anonymous method. But I want to use it without anonymous function. So that I could call remove event listner later.
Please see the not disabled condition in initAndSetupTheSliders function.

```
var apprange = function () {
 function initAndSetupTheSliders(rangeValue, disabled = false,limitValue) {
  var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input'));
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.setAttribute('value', rangeValue);});
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {return apprange.updateSlider(input,limitValue, disabled);});
    // Cross-browser support where value changes instantly as you drag the handle, therefore two event types.
  if(!disabled){
############## Following two lines are not working as it should. ############
   inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.addEventListener('input', eventHandler(input, limitValue, disabled));});
   inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.addEventListener('change', eventHandler(input, limitValue, disabled));});
############# Code end ##################
  }else{
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.removeEventListener('input', eventHandler(input, limitValue, disabled));});
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.removeEventListener('change', eventHandler(input, limitValue, disabled));});
     console.log('#### 2');
    }
    
   }
   function eventHandler(input,limitValue, disabled){
    return apprange.updateSlider(input,limitValue, disabled);
   }
   function updateSlider(element, limitValue, disabled) {
    
     if (element) {
      
     var parent = element.parentElement,
     lastValue = parent.getAttribute('data-slider-value');

     if (lastValue === element.value) {
      return; // No value change, no need to update then
     }

     parent.setAttribute('data-slider-value', element.value);
     var $thumb = parent.querySelector('.range-slider__thumb'),
     $bar = parent.querySelector('.range-slider__bar'),
     $thumbLine = parent.querySelector('.range-slider__line'),
     pct = element.value * ((parent.clientHeight - $thumb.clientHeight) / parent.clientHeight);
                 pctLimitLine = limitValue * ((parent.clientHeight - $thumb.clientHeight) / parent.clientHeight);
     $thumb.style.bottom = pct + '%';
     $thumbLine.style.bottom = pctLimitLine + 7 + '%';
     $bar.style.height = 'calc(' + pct + '% + ' + $thumb.clientHeight / 2 + 'px)';
     $thumb.textContent = element.value + '';
                 
     document.getElementById('range').value = element.value;
     
     /* Emoticons Margins */
     if(disabled && false){
      var sliderHeight = parent.clientHeight;
      var multiplier = sliderHeight / 100;
      var UpperRegionHeight = (100 - limitValue) * multiplier;
      var LowerRegionHeight = sliderHeight - UpperRegionHeight;
      
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[0].setAttribute("style", "height:"+UpperRegionHeight+"px");
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_high_smily')[0].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px");
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_medium_smily')[0].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px");
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_low_smily')[0].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px");
      if(document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[1] !== undefined){
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[1].setAttribute("style", "height:"+UpperRegionHeight+"px");
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_high_smily')[1].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px");
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_medium_smily')[1].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px");
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_low_smily')[1].setAttribute("style", "height:"+(LowerRegionHeight/3)+"px"); 
      }
      apprange.HighlightSmiley(limitValue, element.value);
     }
     }
   }
   function HighlightSmiley(limitValue, selectedValue){
    if(selectedValue >= limitValue){
     console.log('if');
     document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[0].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
     if(document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[1] !== undefined){
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_max_smily')[1].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
     }
    }else{
     var limitMultiplier = limitValue/3;
     if(selectedValue >= 0 && selectedValue < limitMultiplier){
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_low_smily')[0].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      if(document.getElementsByClassName('icon_low_smily')[1] !== undefined){
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_low_smily')[1].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      }
     }else if(selectedValue >= limitMultiplier && selectedValue < 2*limitMultiplier){
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_medium_smily')[0].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      if(document.getElementsByClassName('icon_medium_smily')[1] !== undefined){
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_medium_smily')[1].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      }
     }else if(selectedValue >= 2*limitMultiplier && selectedValue < limitValue){
      document.getElementsByClassName('icon_high_smily')[0].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      if(document.getElementsByClassName('icon_high_smily')[1] !== undefined){
       document.getElementsByClassName('icon_high_smily')[1].querySelector('img').setAttribute("width", "70px");
      }
     }
    }
   }

   function removeEventHandler(){

   }
   return {
     initAndSetupTheSliders: initAndSetupTheSliders,
     updateSlider: updateSlider,
     HighlightSmiley: HighlightSmiley,
     eventHandler: eventHandler};
 }();
 
    *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      background: #3D3D4A;
      color: white;
      min-height: 400px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .info {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .container {
      padding-top: 40px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    @media (min-height: 500px) {
      .container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }
    }

    .range-slider {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      height: 300px;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .range-slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: -2em;
      left: .5em;
      content: attr(data-slider-value) "%";
      color: white;
      font-size: 90%;
    }
    .range-slider__thumb {
      position: absolute;
      left: 5px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      background: white;
      color: #777;
      font-size: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #3D3D4A;
      border-radius: 50%;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .range-slider__bar {
      left: 12px;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffc000 37%, #c64e13 50%);
      pointer-events: none;
      width: 18px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      writing-mode: bt-lr;
      -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      border: none;
      background: #343440;
      width: 18px;
      border-color: #343440;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-moz-range-track {
      border: none;
      background: #343440;
      width: 18px;
      border-color: #343440;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-track {
      border: none;
      background: white;
      width: 18px;
      border-color: #343440;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #3D3D4A;
      color: transparent;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-fill-lower, .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-fill-upper, .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-tooltip {
      display: none;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .range-slider input[type=range][orient=vertical]::-ms-thumb {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .theme1 {
      background: linear-gradient(pink, deeppink);
    }

    .theme2 {
      background: linear-gradient(tomato, red);
    }

    .theme3 {
      background: linear-gradient(yellow, orange);
    }
    <div class="container">

      <div class="range-slider">
        <input type="range" orient="vertical" min="0" max="100" />
        <div class="range-slider__bar"></div>
        <div class="range-slider__thumb"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The already running example is in following fiddle:
 https://jsfiddle.net/s1Lvrupa/1/

But as I said in question, I want to get rid of anonymous functions.
It will be a big favor for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about how functions work when passed as parameters -- you do the same thing with both addEventListener and forEach. Take one line of your solution:

```
inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.setAttribute('value', '50');});
```

This creates N functions (one for each of the `inputs`), that all do the same thing: take an input element and set that element's `value` attribute to 50. Since they all do the same thing, you can just as well say,

```
inputs.forEach(fixIt);
function fixIt(input) {
    input.setAttribute('value', '50');
}
```

The same goes for addEventListener, but also, event handlers already have access to the element that called them through `evt.target`. Rather than,

```
element.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {return app.updateSlider(element);});
```

you can say,

```
element.addEventListener('input', eventHandler);
function eventHandler(evt) {
    app.updateSlider(evt.target);
}
```

Then, it becomes simple to say,

```
element.removeEventListener('input', eventHandler);
```

Finally, it looks like all the `inputs` are initialized the same way, so you can use the same function to initialize all of them:

```
(function initAndSetupTheSliders() {
    var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input'));
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.setAttribute('value', '50');});
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {return app.updateSlider(input);});
    // Cross-browser support where value changes instantly as you drag the handle, therefore two event types.
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.addEventListener('input', function (element) {return app.updateSlider(input);});});
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {return input.addEventListener('change', function (element) {return app.updateSlider(input);});});
})();
```

becomes:

```
function initSlider(element) {
    element.setAttribute('value', '50');
    app.updateSlider(element);
    element.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {return app.updateSlider(element);});
    element.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {return app.updateSlider(element);});
}

document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input')).forEach(initSlider);
```

So all together, to avoid anonymous functions and to add the ability to disable a slider, you'd have:

```
function initSlider(element) {
    element.setAttribute('value', '50');
    app.updateSlider(element);
    element.addEventListener('input', eventHandler);
    element.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input').forEach(initSlider)

function eventHandler(evt) {
    return app.updateSlider(evt.target);
}

function unInitSlider(element) {
    element.removeEventListener('input', eventHandler);
    element.removeEventListener('change', eventHandler);
}

unInitSlider(document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider input')[1]);
```